# What is the proper way to write a firm's name?

Tags: names

What is the proper way to write a firm's name?  Would it be Someone, Someone, & Associates or Someone, Someone & Associates or no commas at all?

Comment: Each firm decides what its name is, and different firms do it differently. Look at their letterhead or website.

Comment: It is best to search your main competitors' names and try to follow them. Different companies have quite distinct ways to name their companies. For example, X & Associates are usually used for a law/accounting firm. It won't be that difficult for you to search it.

Comment: @TimLymington, I searched thoroughly to make sure it wasn't a duplicate before I asked my question. I wanted to know specifically how to write the company's name if the partners' last names are the name of the company, as in the example I provided.

Comment: @Shannon There isn't a single practice. Skadden, Arps, Slate, Meagher & Flom LLP. But Akin Gump Strauss Hauer & Feld. But Robinson, Silverman, Pearce, Aronsohn, and Berman. But DLA Piper. Pick one, or none.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write the name of a firm is however the firm writes it. There are different acceptable styles for commas in lists, so always follow the style they have chosen. Likewise for spelling, punctuation and capitalization. For example: [eBay](https://ca.news.yahoo.com/blogs/daily-buzz/ebay-mixup-woman-orders-glass-table-receives-184645078.html), [Inglourious Basterds](http://www.uphe.com/movies/inglourious-basterds)